# Cookie Policy information corrupts Entity payload in POST request to REST webservice

Tags: android, rest, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for reading this (first stackoverflow post..yaay ^^)

I'm trying to send a POST request with a JSON payload and a cookie (containing authentification information) to a REST webservice.
The JavaEE-Server reads the HttpServletRequest's InputStream but **the last 23 bytes are missing (even though they are in the request)**. The server works fine with requests sent via curl or this [Java RESTClient](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) (by WizTools.org)

When looking at the Packet that was sent I noticed that **the amount of bytes that are ignored when reading the inputStream is the same amount of data as the description of the accepted Cookies i.e. Cookie2: $Version=1\r\n**

So what is probably happening is that the requests content-length is correct for the JSONdata (27 Bytes), but because the inputStream includes the 'Cookie2: $Version=1\r\n' (23 bytes) only 4 bytes of the JSON String get read before the Reader exits.

Now the problem: I cant get rid of the CookiePolicy information!

### JavaCode from within an AsyncTask :

(GET Requests using the Cookie are working fine btw)

```
private void addCookieToClient(DefaultHttpClient httpClient){
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(JSONFactory.USER_CREDS, BobManager.getCreds());
    cookie.setDomain(domain);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookieStore.clear();
    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
    httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
    String uri = (String) params[0];

    JSONObject jerg = new JSONObject();
    String response;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    //GET if JSONRequest is null
    if(requestJSON==null){
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
        try {
            addCookieToClient((DefaultHttpClient)httpClient);
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,responseHandler);
            jerg = new JSONObject(response);
        } 
        //catching stuff  
        }finally{
            return jerg;
        }
    }
    //POST
    else{
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(uri);
        try {
            addCookieToClient((DefaultHttpClient)httpClient);
            StringEntity en = new StringEntity(requestJSON.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
            postMethod.setEntity(en);
            postMethod.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            postMethod.setHeader("charset", HTTP.UTF_8);

            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
            jerg = new JSONObject(result);
        } 
        //catching stuff
        }finally{
            return jerg;
        }
    }
}
```

### What is sent

**wireshark** shows and marks exactly the data as JSON payload that the InputStream returns and also shows that the rest of the JSON is present in the request:

[Link to image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1carVOm9Lxeb0ZXSjhqaW9JN2c/edit?usp=sharing)

...sorry, not enough credits to post pics here ^^

the **httpclient wire logs** seem okay to me (dont know about the [EndOfLines] surrounding the Cookie2 parameter though?!) - thanks to oleg for the hint:

```
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "POST /bob/srv/item/react HTTP/1.1[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "Content-Type: application/json[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "Accept: application/json[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "charset: UTF-8[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "Content-Length: 27[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "Content-Encoding: UTF-8[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "Host: 192.168.178.23:8080[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "Cookie: creds=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[\n]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "Cookie2: $Version=1[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "[EOL]"
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> POST /bob/srv/item/react HTTP/1.1
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> Content-Type: application/json
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> Accept: application/json
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> charset: UTF-8
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> Content-Length: 27
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> Content-Encoding: UTF-8
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> Host: 192.168.178.23:8080
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> Connection: Keep-Alive
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> Cookie: creds=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
D/org.apache.http.headers: >> Cookie2: $Version=1
D/org.apache.http.wire: >> "{"id":3,"answervalueint":4}"
```

### What i tried to get rid of it

changing the parameter for cookie policy worked, but only resulted in different content influencing the supposed payload and with that a different offset than 23 bytes, e.g. the following resulted in a 2 byte offset (only the chars '\r\n' instead of 'Cookie2: $Version=1\r\n' disturb with that setting):

```
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
```

removing the parameter did not work as it defaulted to 'Cookie2: $Version=1\r\n'

```
httpClient.getParams().removeParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY);
```

I have a very dirty workaround now, but help of how to get rid of the CookiePolicy Information or infos on why it is handled like it is part of the JSON payload are greatly appreciated =)

thanks and best regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first EOL in the request is the problem, because the message body is supposed to start after the first blank line of the request.

Knowing this helped me find out that the value of the 'creds' cookie ended with a line break. using the flag NO_WRAP when creating that Base64 encoded String eliminated the problem.

Thanks to oleg for helping me to narrow down my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Length of the HTTP message head (request line or status line plus headers) and that of content entity (body) are *completely* unrelated. Cookie2 header has nothing to do with your issue.

You can turn on wire logging to see exact composition of HTTP messages HttpClient transmits across the wire

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

Comment: thanks for the hint towards wire logging and the info oleg
i added the logs to my question - with the exception of the EOLs surrounding the suspicious Cookie2 parameter the logs seem okay to me.
i still have no clue why that parameter directly influences the size of the offset in the InputStream. which can also be seen in the linked image showing that wirshark 'thinks' that the parameter and two EOLs are part of the 'Line-based text data'JSON content